# Does Hybis support a CMS component for video?

Tags: e-commerce, sap-commerce-cloud

Just like image components in Hybris CMS, which can be managed by business users, do we have out-of-the-box support for video components?
If no, how can we go about creating one?

Proposed solution:

1. Extend an CMSSimpleComponent
2. Add video path (URL) attribute.
3. Set this attribute to video media URL.
4. To render (not so sure!)

Please provide feedback if this approach is fine.

Comment: This article answers exactly this question : https://www.stackextend.com/hybris/create-a-custom-cms-component-in-hybris/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of an out of the box one (unless they added one in recent versions) so yes, you will have to create one.

Your solution approach looks about right to me, however If it were me I would have the component attribute as type MediaContainer.

That way, you can reference a MediaContainer that has multiple formats of the video (e.g. multiple resolutions/dimensions) so that your component can select the correct one for different clients.

In terms of how to actually play the video, I highly recommend encoding your videos with h.264 so that the browser can play it natively and then selecting a JavaScript library to add player controls.

E.g. http://videojs.com/

You should also consider how you will use a CDN. Do not serve video content direct to your consumers from your server. Use a CDN.

Worth noting is that there are several CDN providers that can handle resizing and cropping of both images and video for you, which makes life much much easier as you only need to hold the original. See here:

http://cloudinary.com/blog/video_transcoding_resizing_cropping_and_manipulating_made_easy